# Is there a way to have a "User" place a button widget on an interactive viewer. (Like a Floorplan Builder)

Tags: android, flutter, dart

I am building an app that allows the user to build their gyms floorplan and place buttons where the machines would be.

I am currently using an Interactive Viewer to display the floorplan. I need the functionality to create a button widget where the "User" long-presses.

Here is my Current Code with the `onLongPressEnd` class.

```
Padding(
              padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 1),
              child: Center(
                child: GestureDetector(
                  onLongPressEnd: ((details) => {

//Code to create button goes here

                      }),
                  child: InteractiveViewer(
                    minScale: 1,
                    maxScale: 2,
                    child: Stack(
                      children: [
                        Image.asset(
                            'Assets/Lift View Images/room_layout_1.png'),
                          );
```

Someone on the internet has posted an almost identical problem to this and created a whole solution, the problem is since his solution, the `InteractiveViewer` widget has been added so all of his code is obsolete and cannot be copied to a newer version.

[https://medium.com/@alexander.arendar/dragging-zooming-and-placing-object-on-indoor-map-with-flutter-67667ef415ec](https://www.stackoverflow.com/)

In conclusion I need the functionality for the user to create pre defined widgets by pressing on the page.

Full Code [https://github.com/CokeMango/mapview_iteration_1.git](https://www.stackoverflow.com/)

I tried for hours to understand this documents solution, [https://medium.com/@alexander.arendar/dragging-zooming-and-placing-object-on-indoor-map-with-flutter-67667ef415ec](https://www.stackoverflow.com/) but never figured out how to implement it with the Interactive Viewer widget. And being fairly new to Flutter I couldn't replicate it exactly.

I also searched online for a while and at most I found what I already had which was a zoomable scrollable image viewer with no functionality.

Comment: and do you want your buttons to be scaled when `InteractiveViewer` is scaled? or just their center points should be pinned to fixed positions on the floor plan without resizing buttons size?

Comment: I would prefer the buttons to also be resized, when the InteractiveViewer is manipulated.

Comment: so simply add them as `InteractiveViewer` (grand)children and thy will be scaled automatically

Comment: I need the user to be able to place them. Like a floorplan editor. like this [link](https://www.google.com/search?q=floorplan+creator&rlz=1C1UEAD_enUS1007US1007&tbm=isch&sxsrf=AJOqlzXDfVEhKvNsAZnGtcPtmuOK1u2sWw:1673679323583&source=lnms&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwiE-bKsvcb8AhVpElkFHWSQBUAQ_AUoAXoECAoQAw&biw=1920&bih=975&dpr=1#imgrc=GZ0596hBe0HyaM)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

here you can see two approaches: `FloorPlanWithFixedButtons` adds "buttons" with a fixed size (no matter what the current zoom factor is used by `InteractiveViewer`), while `FloorPlanWithScaledButtons` adds "buttons" directly to `InteractiveViewer` so they are automatically scaled when you zoom-in / zoom-out

if you need draggable "buttons" check `FloorPlanWithScaledDraggableButtons` widget

```
class ChipEntry {
  ChipEntry({
    required this.offset,
    required this.label,
  });

  Offset offset;
  final String label;
}
```

**FloorPlanWithFixedButtons**

```
class FloorPlanWithFixedButtons extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  State<FloorPlanWithFixedButtons> createState() => _FloorPlanWithFixedButtonsState();
}

class _FloorPlanWithFixedButtonsState extends State<FloorPlanWithFixedButtons> with TickerProviderStateMixin {
  int animatedIndex = -1;
  late final controller = AnimationController(vsync: this, duration: const Duration(milliseconds: 250));
  final chips = <ChipEntry>[];
  final transformationController = TransformationController();
  int labelNumber = 0;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Column(
      children: [
        const Padding(
          padding: EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
          child: Text('1) long press on the floor plan below to add a new button\n'),
        ),
        Expanded(
          child: ClipRect(
            child: GestureDetector(
              onLongPressStart: _addButton,
              child: Stack(
                children: [
                  InteractiveViewer(
                    minScale: 1,
                    maxScale: 5,
                    constrained: false,
                    transformationController: transformationController,
                    // https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/9/9a/Sample_Floorplan.jpg/640px-Sample_Floorplan.jpg
                    child: Image.asset('images/640px-Sample_Floorplan.jpg'),
                  ),
                  CustomMultiChildLayout(
                    delegate: FloorPlanDelegate(
                      chips: chips,
                      transformationController: transformationController,
                    ),
                    children: [
                      for (int index = 0; index < chips.length; index++)
                        LayoutId(id: index, child: _button(index)),
                    ],
                  ),
                ],
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ],
    );
  }

  Widget _button(int index) {
    final button = Chip(
      backgroundColor: Colors.orange,
      side: const BorderSide(width: 1, color: Colors.black12),
      elevation: 4,
      onDeleted: () async {
        setState(() {
          animatedIndex = index;
        });
        await controller.reverse(from: 1.0);
        setState(() {
          chips.removeAt(index);
          animatedIndex = -1;
        });
      },
      label: InkWell(
        onTap: () => print('button |${chips[index].label}| at index $index pressed'),
        child: Text(chips[index].label),
      ),
    );
    return index == animatedIndex? ScaleTransition(scale: controller, child: button) : button;
  }

  void _addButton(LongPressStartDetails details) async {
    setState(() {
      animatedIndex = chips.length;
      final chipEntry = ChipEntry(
        offset: transformationController.toScene(details.localPosition),
        label: 'btn #$labelNumber'
      );
      chips.add(chipEntry);
      labelNumber++;
    });
    await controller.forward(from: 0.0);
    animatedIndex = -1;
  }
}

class FloorPlanDelegate extends MultiChildLayoutDelegate {
  FloorPlanDelegate({
    required this.chips,
    required this.transformationController,
  }) : super(relayout: transformationController); // NOTE: this is very important

  final List<ChipEntry> chips;
  final TransformationController transformationController;

  @override
  void performLayout(ui.Size size) {
    // print('performLayout $size');
    int id = 0;
    final constraints = BoxConstraints.loose(size);
    final matrix = transformationController.value;
    for (final chip in chips) {
      final size = layoutChild(id, constraints);
      final offset = MatrixUtils.transformPoint(matrix, chip.offset) - size.center(Offset.zero);
      positionChild(id, offset);
      id++;
    }
  }

  @override
  bool shouldRelayout(covariant MultiChildLayoutDelegate oldDelegate) => false;
}
```

**FloorPlanWithScaledButtons**

```
class FloorPlanWithScaledButtons extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  State<FloorPlanWithScaledButtons> createState() => _FloorPlanWithScaledButtonsState();
}

class _FloorPlanWithScaledButtonsState extends State<FloorPlanWithScaledButtons> with TickerProviderStateMixin {
  int animatedIndex = -1;
  late final controller = AnimationController(vsync: this, duration: const Duration(milliseconds: 250));
  final chips = <ChipEntry>[];
  final transformationController = TransformationController();
  int labelNumber = 0;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Column(
      children: [
        const Padding(
          padding: EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
          child: Text('1) long press on the floor plan below to add a new button\n'),
        ),
        Expanded(
          child: ClipRect(
            child: GestureDetector(
              onLongPressStart: _addButton,
              child: InteractiveViewer(
                minScale: 1,
                maxScale: 5,
                constrained: false,
                transformationController: transformationController,
                child: Stack(
                  children: [
                    // https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/9/9a/Sample_Floorplan.jpg/640px-Sample_Floorplan.jpg
                    Image.asset('images/640px-Sample_Floorplan.jpg'),
                    ...chips.mapIndexed(_positionedButton),
                  ],
                ),
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ],
    );
  }

  Widget _positionedButton(int index, ChipEntry chip) {
    final child = Chip(
      backgroundColor: Colors.orange,
      side: const BorderSide(width: 1, color: Colors.black12),
      elevation: 4,
      onDeleted: () async {
        setState(() {
          animatedIndex = index;
        });
        await controller.reverse(from: 1.0);
        setState(() {
          chips.removeAt(index);
          animatedIndex = -1;
        });
      },
      label: InkWell(
        onTap: () => print('button |${chip.label}| at index $index pressed'),
        child: Text(chip.label),
      ),
    );

    return Positioned(
      left: chip.offset.dx,
      top: chip.offset.dy,
      child: FractionalTranslation(
        translation: const Offset(-0.5, -0.5),
        child: index == animatedIndex? ScaleTransition(scale: controller, child: child) : child,
      ),
    );
  }

  void _addButton(LongPressStartDetails details) async {
    setState(() {
      animatedIndex = chips.length;
      final chipEntry = ChipEntry(
        offset: transformationController.toScene(details.localPosition),
        label: 'btn #$labelNumber'
      );
      chips.add(chipEntry);
      labelNumber++;
    });
    await controller.forward(from: 0.0);
    animatedIndex = -1;
  }
}
```

**FloorPlanWithScaledDraggableButtons**

```
class FloorPlanWithScaledDraggableButtons extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  State<FloorPlanWithScaledDraggableButtons> createState() => _FloorPlanWithScaledDraggableButtonsState();
}

class _FloorPlanWithScaledDraggableButtonsState extends State<FloorPlanWithScaledDraggableButtons> {
  final chips = <ChipEntry>[];
  final transformationController = TransformationController();
  int labelNumber = 0;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Column(
      children: [
        const Padding(
          padding: EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
          child: Text('1) long press on the floor plan below to add a new button\n'
          '2) long press on the added button to drag it'),
        ),
        Expanded(
          child: ClipRect(
            child: GestureDetector(
              onLongPressStart: _addButton,
              child: InteractiveViewer(
                minScale: 1,
                maxScale: 5,
                constrained: false,
                transformationController: transformationController,
                child: Stack(
                  children: [
                    // https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/9/9a/Sample_Floorplan.jpg/640px-Sample_Floorplan.jpg
                    Image.asset('images/640px-Sample_Floorplan.jpg'),
                    ...chips.mapIndexed(_button),
                  ],
                ),
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ],
    );
  }

  Widget _button(int index, ChipEntry chip) {
    return DraggableChip(
      chip: chip,
      onTap: () => print('button |${chip.label}| at index $index pressed'),
      onDrag: (delta) => setState(() => chip.offset += _scaled(delta)),
      onDeleted: () => setState(() => chips.removeAt(index)),
    );
  }

  Offset _scaled(Offset delta) {
    return delta / transformationController.value.getMaxScaleOnAxis();
  }

  void _addButton(LongPressStartDetails details) {
    setState(() {
      final chipEntry = ChipEntry(
        offset: transformationController.toScene(details.localPosition),
        label: 'btn #$labelNumber'
      );
      chips.add(chipEntry);
      labelNumber++;
    });
  }
}

class DraggableChip extends StatefulWidget {
  const DraggableChip({
    Key? key,
    required this.chip,
    this.onTap,
    this.onDrag,
    this.onDeleted,
  }) : super(key: key);

  final ChipEntry chip;
  final VoidCallback? onTap;
  final Function(Offset)? onDrag;
  final VoidCallback? onDeleted;

  @override
  State<DraggableChip> createState() => _DraggableChipState();
}

class _DraggableChipState extends State<DraggableChip> with SingleTickerProviderStateMixin {
  late final controller = AnimationController(vsync: this, duration: const Duration(milliseconds: 250));
  bool drag = false;
  Offset position = Offset.zero;
  double scale = 0;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    controller.forward();
  }

  @override
  void didUpdateWidget(covariant DraggableChip oldWidget) {
    super.didUpdateWidget(oldWidget);
    scale = controller.value = 1;
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final child = RawChip(
      selected: drag,
      showCheckmark: false,
      selectedColor: Colors.teal,
      backgroundColor: Colors.orange,
      side: const BorderSide(width: 1, color: Colors.black12),
      elevation: 4,
      onDeleted: () async {
        await controller.reverse();
        widget.onDeleted?.call();
      },
      label: GestureDetector(
        onLongPressStart: (d) => setState(() {
          drag = true;
          position = d.globalPosition;
        }),
        onLongPressMoveUpdate: (d) {
          widget.onDrag?.call(d.globalPosition - position);
          position = d.globalPosition;
        },
        onLongPressEnd: (d) => setState(() => drag = false),
        child: InkWell(
          onTap: widget.onTap,
          child: Text(widget.chip.label),
        ),
      ),
    );
    return Positioned(
      left: widget.chip.offset.dx,
      top: widget.chip.offset.dy,
      child: FractionalTranslation(
        translation: const Offset(-0.5, -0.5),
        child: ScaleTransition(
        scale: controller,
          child: child,
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank You, this looks to be a perfect solution to my problem. However the only problem I am having is with the 'ChipEntry' class. My IDE (VSCODE) is calling it as a bug and returns this,                                                                                                                    
                                                                                                                                             
  "The name 'ChipEntry' isn't a type so it can't be used as a type argument.
Try the name to an existing type, or defining a type named 'ChipEntry'"

Comment: This is only a problem for the Scalable versions, however in the Fixed Buttons version there is an error with the 'ui.Size' class, saying that it is undefined.

Comment: @CokeMango `ChipEntry` class is defined in the first code snippet, just copy it, for `ui.Size` you need `import 'dart:ui' as ui;`