# Is there a possibility in FLUTTER to draw a horizontal plan with adding, modifying and moving objects?

Tags: flutter

Is there a possibility in FLUTTER to draw a horizontal plan with adding, modifying and moving objects?

draw or image and put overlay objects for illustrative

[image: 1]

we did it before in javascript with overlays

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75090991/is-there-a-way-to-have-a-user-place-a-button-widget-on-an-interactive-viewer#75116364

Comment: Hi Hakeem,
I would try to move your question to the body of this post instead of the title and try to elaborate a bit more on what you want to achieve. There are definitely multiple possibilities for this, but for now the question is a bit too broad. Changing your post might get you more actionable answers

Comment: Yes pskink, that's what I'm looking for, thank you very much Pskink.