# Flutter: InteractiveViewer with a child that does not change its size

Tags: flutter

I would like to use InteractiveViewer to zoom and pan an image.
On top of that image I want to position another widget which should always have a fixed size and mark a specific location on the image.
Think of a pin on a map. The map can be zoomed but the pin keeps its initial size.

Something like this:

```
InteractiveViewer(
  child: Stack(
    children: [
      Image.network('http://placekitten.com/400/400'),
      const Positioned(
        left: 100,
        top: 100,
        child: SizedBox( //    <-- this should not change its size 
          width: 24,
          height: 24,
          child: Icon(Icons.pin_drop, color: Colors.red),
        ),
      ),
    ],
  ),
);
```

I can't prevent the pin from changing it's size when the image is zoomed.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75090991/is-there-a-way-to-have-a-user-place-a-button-widget-on-an-interactive-viewer#75116364 - the first case

Comment: My first thought is to put the InteractiveViewer inside the Stack.