# how do I add a marker to an image by clicking ontap?

Tags: flutter, dart, dictionary, google-maps-markers, gesturedetector

[image]

I want to do something similar, but I can't figure out how to put my image instead of a map and how to set markers by clicking. So that when you click onTap, a marker appears and saves its location.

I tried to create custom markers on the map, but I can't substitute my image in any way.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75090991/is-there-a-way-to-have-a-user-place-a-button-widget-on-an-interactive-viewer#75116364

Answer (score 0):

This is how u add marker on image.

```
          late ui.Image image;
          bool isImageloaded = false;
          GlobalKey _myCanvasKey = new GlobalKey();
        
          @override
          void initState() {
            super.initState();
            init();
          }
        
            Future<Null> init() async {
                final ByteData data =
                    await rootBundle.load('assets/images/frame_162778.jpg');
                image = await loadImage(Uint8List.view(data.buffer));
              }
            
              Future<ui.Image> loadImage(Uint8List img) async {
                final Completer<ui.Image> completer = Completer();
                ui.decodeImageFromList(img, (ui.Image img) {
                  setState(() {
                    isImageloaded = true;
                  });
                  return completer.complete(img);
                });
                return completer.future;
              }
            
            @override
              Widget build(BuildContext context) {
                CustomMarkerPainter painter = CustomMarkerPainter(image: image);
                ...
                                  FittedBox(
                                    child: SizedBox(
                                      height: image.height.toDouble(),
                                      width: image.width.toDouble(),
                                      child: Padding(
                                        padding: EdgeInsetsDirectional.fromSTEB(
                                            0.0, 12.0, 0.0, 12.0),
                                        child: GestureDetector(
                                          onTapDown: (details) {
                                            painter.update(details.localPosition);
                                            _myCanvasKey.currentContext!
                                                .findRenderObject()!
                                                .markNeedsPaint();
                                          },
                                          child: CustomPaint(
                                            key: _myCanvasKey,
                                            painter: painter,
                                          ),
                                        ),
                                      ),
                                    ),
                                  );
            }
                
            class CustomMarkerPainter extends CustomPainter {
                  CustomMarkerPainter({
                    required this.image,
                  });
                
                  ui.Image image;
                
                  Offset point = Offset(0, 0);
                
                  final Paint painter = new Paint()
                    ..color = Colors.blue
                    ..style = PaintingStyle.fill;
                
                  void update(Offset offset) {
                    point = offset;
                  }
                
                  @override
                  void paint(Canvas canvas, Size size) {
                    canvas.drawImage(image, Offset(0.0, 0.0), Paint());
                    canvas.drawCircle(point, 10, painter);
                  }
                
                  @override
                  bool shouldRepaint(CustomPainter oldDelegate) {
                    return true;
                  }
                }
```

Comment: Thank you for contributing to the Stack Overflow community. This may be a correct answer, but it’d be really useful to provide additional explanation of your code so developers can understand your reasoning. This is especially useful for new developers who aren’t as familiar with the syntax or struggling to understand the concepts. **Would you kindly [edit] your answer to include additional details for the benefit of the community?**