# Adaptive container on picture in Flutter

Tags: android, flutter, image, containers

Is there way in flutter to put container on image and lock it on it, so when I will zoom the picture, the container zoom to and stays on picture? Need it for my map app for school.

When I tried it, the picture couldn't have been zoomed.

Comment: check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75090991/is-there-a-way-to-have-a-user-place-a-button-widget-on-an-interactive-viewer#75116364

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this by using the `InteractiveViewer` widget
I have put some `Icons` over an `Image` which **move** and **zoom** along with **background** `Image`.

> You can use any `widget` you want to plot over an `Image` in `Stack`

```
Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: const Text('Mehran Ullah Khan'),
      ),
      body: InteractiveViewer.builder(
        scaleEnabled: true,
         builder: (context, quad) {
          return const Stack(
            children: [
              FlutterLogo(
                size: 1000,
              ),
              Positioned(
                  top: 200,
                  left: 200,
                  child: Icon(
                    Icons.location_pin,
                    size: 60,
                    color: Colors.black,
                  )),
              Positioned(
                  top: 250,
                  left: 250,
                  child: Icon(
                    Icons.location_pin,
                    size: 60,
                    color: Colors.black,
                  )),
              Positioned(
                  top: 300,
                  left: 300,
                  child: Icon(
                    Icons.location_pin,
                    size: 60,
                    color: Colors.black,
                  )),
            ],
          );
        },
      ),
    )
```