# Icon movement on an image

Tags: android, flutter

i'm creating a flutter app with the following functions. an image has  to be loaded using photo_view package. also an icon needs to be shown on the image. if the user scales the image, icon size should remain same but it's position should get adjusted as per zoomed scale so that icon remains at the same point. user should also have an option to to drag the icon and place it wherever inside the widget. this drag can happen at any scale of the image. the amount of movement of icon in the scaled image has be captured correctly to re-position the icon if user changes the scale after movement. the main goal is to correctly adjust the position of icon in scale 1 (non zoomed) even when icon movement happens at a different scale.how can this be done?

following is the calculation i'm doing now which does not seem to work.
value is taken by PhotoViewController.

```
child: Listener(
                  onPointerMove: (event) {
                    setState(() {
                      final scale = value.scale!;
                      final position = value.position;

                      _currentIconOffsets[index] = Offset(
                        _currentIconOffsets[index].dx + event.delta.dx,
                        _currentIconOffsets[index].dy + event.delta.dy,
                      );

                      
                      _iconInitialPositions[index] = Offset(((_currentIconOffsets[index].dx - (position.dx / scale)) / scale) , ((_currentIconOffsets[index].dy - (position.dy / scale)) / scale));
                    });
                    
                  },
                  child: Draggable(
                    child: Image.asset(_iconPaths[index]),
                    feedback: Image.asset(_iconPaths[index]),
                    childWhenDragging: Container(),
                  ),
                ),
```

Comment: check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75090991/is-there-a-way-to-have-a-user-place-a-button-widget-on-an-interactive-viewer#75116364, version `FloorPlanWithFixedButtons`

Comment: thanks for the quick reply. i would like to have something like **FloorPlanWithFixedDraggableButtons**. what do i have to do? @pskink

Comment: so you would need to find how `FloorPlanWithScaledDraggableButtons` differs from `FloorPlanWithScaledButtons` and apply those changes to `FloorPlanWithFixedButtons`

Comment: i did changes as per your answer. i could not make it work. still, button gets zoomed when i scale the image. i'm able to drag the scaled button but the movement is not linear. where i'm wrong? thanks. @pskink

Comment: in `FloorPlanWithFixedButtons` do icons scale when you zoom in/out?

Comment: No. That means, i've done something wrong while creating a new class. My requirement should be achivable by doing changes to the existing 3 classes is what you are suggesting?