How to optimize a CustomPainter drawing application in Flutter?
I'm implementing a feature so the user can paint freely in a canvas in the screen. The expected behaviour is working very nicely: I can change the brush size and color and erase the drawing thanks to the call to canvas.saveLayer and canvas.restore.
The main issue happens when I've accumulated enough drawings to make the paint method very expensive to the application. I don't think adding RepaintBoundary will actually improve this, because so far the method is repainting the whole drawing as the user keeps drawing and its performance gets progressively worse, reaching 1 fps if you push so far.
Here is the code:
class DrawingCanvas extends StatefulWidget {
  const DrawingCanvas({
    super.key,
    required this.onPanUpdate,
    required this.onPanEnd,
    required this.initialDrawings,
    required this.selectedPainter,
    this.boundarySize = Size.infinite,
  });

  final List<DrawingDetails> initialDrawings;
  final void Function(Offset?) onPanUpdate;
  final void Function(Offset?) onPanEnd;
  final Paint selectedPainter;
  final Size boundarySize;

  @override
  State<DrawingCanvas> createState() => _DrawingCanvasState();
}

class _DrawingCanvasState extends State<DrawingCanvas> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return GestureDetector(
      onPanStart: (details) {
        setState(() {
          widget.onPanUpdate(details.localPosition);
        });
      },
      onPanUpdate: (details) {
        setState(() {
          widget.onPanUpdate(details.localPosition);
        });
      },
      onPanEnd: (details) {
        setState(() {
          widget.onPanEnd(null);
        });
      },
      child: CustomPaint(
        isComplex: true,
        painter: _DrawingPainter(
          initialDrawings: widget.initialDrawings,
          selectedPainter: widget.selectedPainter,
          boundarySize: widget.boundarySize,
        ),
        size: Size.infinite,
      ),
    );
  }
}

class _DrawingPainter extends CustomPainter {
  final List<DrawingDetails> initialDrawings;
  final Paint selectedPainter;
  final Logger logger = Logger('_DrawingPainter');
  final Size boundarySize;

  _DrawingPainter({
    required this.initialDrawings,
    required this.selectedPainter,
    required this.boundarySize,
  });

  @override
  bool shouldRepaint(_DrawingPainter oldDelegate) {
    return true;
  }

  void paint(Canvas canvas, Size size) {
    canvas.saveLayer(Rect.largest, Paint());
    for (DrawingDetails drawing in initialDrawings) {
      for (int i = 0; i < drawing.points.length - 1; i++) {
        if (drawing.points[i] != null && drawing.points[i + 1] != null) {
          canvas.drawLine(
            drawing.points[i]!,
            drawing.points[i + 1]!,
            drawing.painterOptions.painter,
          );
        }
      }
    }
    canvas.restore();
  }
}


I've also tried to avoid adding the same offset to the list if it is repeated, but it improves just a little bit, but doesn't keep the issue from happening.
Anyone has a suggestion on how I can solve this issue?
Is there any improvement I am oblivious to?

you can checkout graphx,flame for this

instead of drawing everything using Canvas.drawLine try to convert after each (for example) 1000 points your canvas to Image - you do that with Canvas(PictureRecorder) ctor and then calling 1000 times Canvas.drawLine followed by Picure.toImage[Sync] - now your 1000 points can be drawn with simple Cnavas.drawImage

but first maybe try simple Canvas.drawPoints with PointMode.polygon?

Thanks, I'll try the simple one first and then caching if this one doesn't work. I'll probably do it on monday, so I'll mark any answer as correct then, don't worry xD
@Md.YeasinSheikh do you mean graphx.flame from this package: https://github.com/roipeker/graph ?

yap I like those

hey @pskink  what do you prefer to position N widgets at a specific offset, draw line between them and receive a tap event, e.g family tree ?

@Md.YeasinSheikh either Flow or CustomMultiChildLayout + of course CustomPaint

thanks, I was wondering if it is just possible with single one. for the lines  seems can't avoid CustomPaint or do we have paint method on those. Also like to have 2D scrollView or maybe for now just InteractiveViewer.  would you prefer customMultiChildLayout over Flow?

@Md.YeasinSheikh you can still use InteractiveViewer with either Flow or CustomMultiChildLayout like https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75090991/is-there-a-way-to-have-a-user-place-a-button-widget-on-an-interactive-viewer/75116364#75116364, btw if you want to use Flow check https://gist.github.com/pskink/10c8fd372113f0b36570db96d58d818e#file-flow_painting_context_extension-dart

@Md.YeasinSheikh i would forget: there is a widget combining  custom layout and painter: https://gist.github.com/pskink/10c8fd372113f0b36570db96d58d818e#file-flow_painter-dart - everything has 77 lines: you can remove the examples that follow

ok thanks, checking  and hope  by removing bunch of snippet, making it small to understand it

@Md.YeasinSheikh good luck then ;-)

I tried it before and failed

The extension. the reason  I left that time bcoz I found another way  of doing it. for current stuffs adding another Layer of CustomPaint on CustomMultiChildLayout will be enough for the time being, If I fail enough, I will get it ✌

pretty  cool, utilizing customPaint,

@Md.YeasinSheikh and what another way you found?

that time used customScrollPhysics with sliverPersistanceHeaderDelegate which worked as desired but this thing is seems complex to me, often stuck on infinite loop, seems tree isn't a good way, DirectGraph might work but I wonder what I will do with this feature, well just another hobby project

I came back to this today and, boy, you guys had some conversation hahaha

Ok, so as suggested by @pskink I've added a logic in which every time the user takes his fingers out of the screen -- or, in other words, finish a line, I store it as an image and erase the previous list of points.
It looks like this:
class DrawingCanvas extends StatelessWidget {
  const DrawingCanvas({
    super.key,
    required this.onTouchStart,
    required this.onTouchUpdate,
    required this.onTouchEnd,
    required this.onCachingDrawing,
    required this.pointsAdded,
    required this.selectedPainter,
    required this.cachedDrawing,
    required this.shouldCacheDrawing,
    required this.pageOneImage,
    this.pageTwoImage,
    required this.child,
  });

  final Widget child;
  final List<DrawingDetails> pointsAdded;
  final void Function(Offset) onTouchStart;
  final void Function(Offset) onTouchUpdate;
  final void Function() onTouchEnd;
  final void Function(ui.Image) onCachingDrawing;
  final ui.Image? cachedDrawing;
  final bool shouldCacheDrawing;
  final Paint selectedPainter;
  final ui.Image? pageOneImage;
  final ui.Image? pageTwoImage;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return GestureDetector(
      onPanStart: (details) {
        onTouchStart(details.globalPosition);
      },
      onPanUpdate: (details) {
        onTouchUpdate(details.globalPosition);
      },
      onPanEnd: (_) {
        onTouchEnd();
      },
      child: ClipPath(
        child: CustomPaint(
          isComplex: true,
          willChange: true,
          foregroundPainter: _DrawingPainter(
            drawings: pointsAdded,
            selectedPainter: selectedPainter,
            onCachingDrawing: onCachingDrawing,
            cachedDrawing: cachedDrawing,
            shouldCacheDrawing: shouldCacheDrawing,
            pageOneImage: pageOneImage,
            pageTwoImage: pageTwoImage,
          ),
          child: child,
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class _DrawingPainter extends CustomPainter {
  final List<DrawingDetails> drawings;
  final Paint selectedPainter;
  final Logger logger = Logger('_DrawingPainter');
  final Function(ui.Image) onCachingDrawing;
  final bool shouldCacheDrawing;
  final ui.Image? cachedDrawing;
  final ui.Image? pageOneImage;
  final ui.Image? pageTwoImage;

  _DrawingPainter({
    required this.drawings,
    required this.selectedPainter,
    required this.onCachingDrawing,
    required this.shouldCacheDrawing,
    required this.pageOneImage,
    this.pageTwoImage,
    this.cachedDrawing,
  });

  @override
  bool shouldRepaint(_DrawingPainter oldDelegate) {
    return (drawings.isNotEmpty &&
            (drawings.length == 1 && drawings[0].points.isNotEmpty)) &&
        oldDelegate.drawings != drawings;
  }

  @override
  void paint(Canvas canvas, Size size) {
    canvas.saveLayer(Rect.largest, Paint());

    final pictureRecorder = ui.PictureRecorder();
    final pictureCanvas = Canvas(pictureRecorder);

    if (cachedDrawing != null) {
      pictureCanvas.drawImage(cachedDrawing!, Offset.zero, Paint());
    }

    for (DrawingDetails drawing in drawings) {
      if (drawing.points.isEmpty) continue;
      if (isPointMode(drawing)) {
        pictureCanvas.drawPoints(
          ui.PointMode.points,
          [drawing.points[0]!],
          drawing.paint,
        );
      } else {
        for (int i = 0; i < drawing.points.length - 1; i++) {
          if (drawing.points[i] != null && drawing.points[i + 1] != null) {
            pictureCanvas.drawLine(
              drawing.points[i]!,
              drawing.points[i + 1]!,
              drawing.paint,
            );
          }
        }
      }
    }

    final picture = pictureRecorder.endRecording();

    canvas.drawPicture(picture);

    if (shouldCacheDrawing) {
      final ui.Image cachedImage = picture.toImageSync(
        size.width.toInt(),
        size.height.toInt(),
      );
      onCachingDrawing(cachedImage);
    }

    canvas.restore();
  }

  bool isPointMode(DrawingDetails drawing) =>
      drawing.points.length == 1 && drawing.points[0] != null;
}

The key is avoiding caching it at every frame using a flag, such as shouldCacheDrawing.
So, thanks you guys and sorry for the delay to post the result.
